# How to use a variable value as a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am desperate - I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I try to replace all occurrences of '8969' but I always get the original string (no matter whether tmp is a string or an int). Maybe it's already too late, maybe I'm blind, ...

```
var tmp = "8969";
alert("8969_8969".replace(/tmp/g, "99"));
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why do you use such expression `/tmp/g`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `/` characters are the container for a regular expression in this case. 'tmp' is therefore not used as a variable, but as a literal string.

```
var tmp = /8969/g;
alert("8969_8969".replace(tmp, "99"));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
alert("8969_8969".replace(/8969/g, "99"));
```

or

```
var tmp = "8969"
alert("8969_8969".replace(new RegExp(tmp,"g"), "99"));
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3EGn/)

Comment: I know this works, but I have the value in a variable ...

Even if I write

    var tmp = 8969;

it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic way of handling a regex:

```
var nRegExp = new RegExp("8969", 'g');
alert("8969_8969".replace(nRegExp, "99"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`/tmp/g`.  This is a regex looking for the phrase `"tmp"`.  You need to use `new RegExp` to make a dynamic regex.

```
alert("8969_8969".replace(new RegExp(tmp,'g'), "99"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript doesn't support **that** usage of tmp, it will try to use 'tmp' literally, as a regex pattern.

```
"8969_8969".replace(new RegExp(tmp,'g'), "99")
```